# Passing Shell command in ansible based on condition

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I m very new to ansible and facing some difficulty in this
I have to pass the full shell command based on some condition in ansible
I tried to set facts but i'm not able to execute the shell and getting error as variable not defined

**msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'commands_to_run' is undefined\n\n**

```
- name: setting command for x
    set_fact:
     commands_to_run: ls -1d /filepath/* | grep app | grep  -E "("{{ id }}".*){2}"
    when: id  == 'X'

  - name:setting command for Y
    set_fact:
     commands_to_run: ls -1d /filepath/* | grep app| grep -e "{{ id }}"
    when: id  != 'X'

  - name: list path
    shell: "{{ commands_to_run }}"
    register: path
```

Shell command that needed to be executed based on the condition is completely different .
Please let me know if it can be done in some other ways

ansible-playbook 2.4.2.0

Thanks in advance

Comment: It should work once you fix the indentation on your `set_fact` tasks. See the examples on [official documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/set_fact_module.html).

Comment: Your playbook does not respect yaml and/or ansible syntax. Please [take Y minutes to learn yaml](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/) and pay attention to indentation and new lines. You should also read through the [Intro to playbooks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#about-playbooks) to learn the basic concepts and syntax. You can validate your playbooks with [yamllint](https://yamllint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and [ansible-lint](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-lint/) prior to posting.

Answer (score 0):

Fix your code identation, following example works :

File **site.yml** :

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - name: setting command for X
    set_fact:
      commands_to_run: "echo Case X"
    when: id == 'X'
  - name: setting command for Y
    set_fact:
      commands_to_run: "echo Case Y"
    when: id != 'X'
  - name: call command
    shell: "{{ commands_to_run }}"
    register: path
```

Call case X : ansible-playbook site.yml -e id=X -v
Call case Y : ansible-playbook site.yml -e id=Y -v

If case Y must be called as default case, you can set a default value:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - name: setting command for Y
    set_fact:
      commands_to_run: "echo Case Y"
  - name: setting command for X
    set_fact:
      commands_to_run: "echo Case X"
    when: id == 'X'
  - name: call command
    shell: "{{ commands_to_run }}"
    register: path
```

And if `id` couldn't be defined, use a default value :

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - name: setting command for Y
    set_fact:
      commands_to_run: "echo Case Y"
  - name: setting command for X
    set_fact:
      commands_to_run: "echo Case X"
    when: id | default('Y') == 'X'
  - name: call command
    shell: "{{ commands_to_run }}"
    register: path
```